# Decimal / Integer Multiplication

Tags: php, integer, decimal, multiplication

I'm new to both and I figured I'd try this out.  Why is this returning 0?

```
$_10kpt = (($_10kp * ($_10k *($gspot / 20))));
echo $_10kpt;
```

_10kpt is undefined, first instance. $_10kp is a decimal(7,3), $gspot is an integer and 20 is obviously an integer.  How would I go about returning some sort of value on this?

```
$_10kp = .417
$_10k = 1.0
$gspot = 1600
```

So it should return 33.36 right?

Comment: Could you please completely rewrite your question? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php
$_10kp = .417;
$_10k = 1.0;
$gspot = 1600;
$_10kpt = (($_10kp * ($_10k *($gspot / 20))));
echo $_10kpt;
?>
```

This returns exactly 33.36 at my test...

Comment: Ya...it's now returning the exact value as you.  I have not changed anything but echo output of the variables.  I don't get it.

Comment: You must allways first set values for variables and then making calculations.. 
I belive that you have missed or mistaken some variable name in your test. And this will cause NULL result.

Answer (score 0):

as long as any of the `defined` variables will be `0` or `NULL` your math will give `0`

following the quote `when in doubt print it out` please dump all variables with it's values to make sure these are non-zero ones.